# Jar protocol and php page

Tags: php, jar, protocols

I have a need to hide a locationbar in a child's page (html) for firefox,
but The parent page is (php).
I found article about that; http://kerneltrap.org/node/65367.

I have now HTML file and .JS file that hide the location bar after signed it.

But there is a php file, php's file that call the html to do what i need.
I found jar protocol can call html without any problem; but Jar can't call php file, is there a solution for that, or jar is not support php.
advise me please

Answer (score 0):

just rename your html file to php and use a include or require to call the php file.  As a php file anything not inside a `<? yourcodehere ?>`  or `<?php yourcodehre ?>` is interpretted as html.